# Retrieve variable from string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to retrieve variables from a string in python and having a tough time.

String looks something like this:

```
"{'_id': ObjectId('636d855390928b1b0392b764'), 'request_id': 99, 'timestamp': '2022-11-10T18:12:19.273576'}"
```

I want to retrieve the following values and assign them to variables:

```
objID = 636d855390928b1b0392b764

reqID = 99

timestamp = 2022-11-10T18:12:19.273576
```

The string will follow this format but obviously the values are random. I have tried using the `import re` library but maybe because of the `''` characters I don't get the correct results.

I tried

```
objectID= re.findall(r'\'.*?\'', s)
```

to test out how this works this gives me everything between '' in a list. However, I want to get a value between `ObjectId('`
I attempted the following:

```
re.findall(r'ObjectId(.+?)',s)
```

But this outputs (. I try to get the '' marks in but I always get an error no matter how I try to include them.

Edit: included attempted code

Comment: A regular expression is the way to go. Show what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: I don't see why the `''` characters would be a problem. You just have to match them in the regexp.

Comment: This string comes from MongoDB?

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your best attempt at the code.

Comment: For example `ObjectId\(?<objID>'(\w+)'\)`

Comment: @PM77-1 I have edited it to include what i attempted, how can I go about reopening this question?